# Unable to display tag name of .xml file ( returns None )

Tags: python, xml

Why does this code return `None` and not name value ? ( the sum of all the `None` displayed in the output is equal to the number of name tag...

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.parse('C:/####/workspace/training_demo/images/235140.xml').getroot()
for type_tag in root.findall('object'):
    value =type_tag.get('name')
    print(value)
```

**output**

```
runfile('C:/####/workspace/training_demo/models/my_ssd_resnet152_v1_fpn/untitled0.py', wdir='C:/####/workspace/training_demo/models/my_ssd_resnet152_v1_fpn')
None
None
None
None
None
None
```

**xml file**

```
<annotation>
    <folder>images</folder>
    <filename>235140.png</filename>
    <path>C:\####\workspace\training_demo\images\235140.png</path>
    <source>
        <database>Unknown</database>
    </source>
    <size>
        <width>640</width>
        <height>640</height>
        <depth>3</depth>
    </size>
    <segmented>0</segmented>
    <object>
        <name>APic</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>108</xmin>
            <ymin>81</ymin>
            <xmax>128</xmax>
            <ymax>108</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
    <object>
        <name>DPic</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>129</xmin>
            <ymin>81</ymin>
            <xmax>149</xmax>
            <ymax>108</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
    <object>
        <name>6Coeur</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>151</xmin>
            <ymin>81</ymin>
            <xmax>170</xmax>
            <ymax>108</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
    <object>
        <name>RTrefle</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>172</xmin>
            <ymin>80</ymin>
            <xmax>192</xmax>
            <ymax>108</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
    <object>
        <name>RCarreau</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>140</xmin>
            <ymin>144</ymin>
            <xmax>160</xmax>
            <ymax>159</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
    <object>
        <name>6Pic</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>160</xmin>
            <ymin>144</ymin>
            <xmax>180</xmax>
            <ymax>159</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
</annotation>
```

Comment: `name` is not an attribute, it is a subelement of `object`.

Comment: @mzjn so how would I get `name` value ?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.findtext

Answer (score 0):

The *find()* or *findtext()* functions in the [ElementTree XML API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) can be used to access a child of a given element. The *get()* function is used to access attributes.

The following code finds all object elements and dumps the text contents. If object does not have a name element then *None* is the printed value.

```
for type_tag in root.findall('object'):
    value = type_tag.findtext('name')
    print(value)
```

**Output:**

```
APic
DPic
6Coeur
RTrefle
RCarreau
6Pic
```